# tmux windows closing due to auto-logout

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm running into an issue with auto-logout when using tmux.

When I open a new window in tmux, $TMOUT is set to 600. This causes the shell to auto-logout on me after a while. I can't overwrite it or unset it because it is read only.
If I start a new bash process in that window, $TMOUT is set to 0 and does not time out on me (the desired behavior).

My question is, why does a new tmux window have different environment settings than a new bash process? How can I change the TMOUT setting for new tmux windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are two possibilities you could check:

- You started tmux from a shell with `TMOUT` exported, so it is in the global environment applied to new panes. Check `tmux showenv -g` and if present remove with `tmux setenv -ug TMOUT`. It should not be necessary to export `TMOUT` in the shell which would avoid this.
- tmux starts login shells by default and one of your shell profiles that is only run by login shells is setting `TMOUT`. Check if you also see if with `bash -l`. If this is the case you can either track down where it is being set or change tmux not to start login shells by changing `default-command`.

Comment: Thank you! The culprit turned out to be the login shell. I fixed it by adding this line to my `.tmux.conf`:  

`set-option -g default-command bash`